# passport of nodejs throw pass is not defined （nodejs 0.12.7）

Tags: node.js, passport.js

my app use `passport` for auth user, but it throw exception sometimes like this:

`ReferenceError: pass is not defined
   at deserialized (node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:345:7)
   at app/app.js:89:10`

the app.js is:

```
    var app, bodyParser, config, cookies, cors, e, express, http, keys, localStrategy, logger, multipart, passport, path, router, server, session, sessionStore, sessionUsed, session_store, util, uuid;

express = require('express');

http = require('http');

path = require('path');

session = require('express-session');

cors = require('cors');

session_store = require('sessionstore');

keys = require("keygrip")(['a', 'b']);

bodyParser = require('body-parser');

cookies = require('cookies').express;

passport = require('passport');

uuid = require('node-uuid');

multipart = require('connect-multiparty');

localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

config = require('./config/config');

util = require('./libs/util');

logger = require('./libs/logger');

sessionStore = session_store.createSessionStore(config.getMemCache());

sessionUsed = session({
  secret: config.getCookieSecret(),
  genid: function() {
    return uuid.v4();
  },
  cookie: {},
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  store: sessionStore
});

app = express();

router = express.Router();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.getServerPort());

app.set('views', __dirname + '/../app/public');

app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(sessionUsed);

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(multipart({
  maxFilesSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024
}));

app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname, '/../app/public')));

app.use(cookies(keys));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

passport.use('local', new localStrategy({
  passReqToCallback: true
}, util.checkUserPassword));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  return done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  return done(null, user);
});

require('./routes/router')(app, router, passport);

server = http.createServer(app);

try {
  server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    return logger.info('Express is running at：' + app.get('port'));
  });
} catch (_error) {
  e = _error;
  console.log(e);
}
```

I have view the code which throw exception, like this
[image]

Comment: Never ever post screenshot's of code. Post the actual code.

Comment: Can you please post the whole module, or at least the part where you import and ( if applicable ) modify the `pass` variable ?
Please also post the code from `app.js:89:10`  Post a comment here after you update a questions.

Comment: the code of app.js have posted, the passport version is v0.2.2, you can install the module by `npm install passport@0.2.2`, and the view the whole code

Answer (score 1):

First, your error is not shown in the screenshot.  In the screenshot, you're showing `line 282` from authenticator.js.  Your error message shows where your problem actually is- `line 345` in `function deserialized`.

The reason for this error is because your deserialized function in your app.js is not passing on a user object.  Your deserialized function is a copy of your serialized function, and it should not be.  Here is what the two should look like:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    })
});
```

Of course, you can't use this deserialization function without changing your serialization function to store the `user.id` or some unique identifier instead of trying to store the whole user.  I don't know what happens when you try serializing the whole user, but I'm confident it's what's causing your problems.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have edit my code as your suggestion, but it not solve my problem

Comment: @sundq Does it work if you use dummy data?  Try putting `done(null, 100)` in serializeUser and `done(null, {"test": "object"})` in deserializeUser, instead of the User.findByID.  If that doesn't work, I would suggest trying it with a newer version of passport.

Comment: the passport I use is the latest version

Comment: @sundq You said you're error is in passport v0.2.2, there's a v0.3.2 out right now.  Also, your error says the error is triggered on line `89:10` in your app.js, which line of code is that?

Comment: It looks like line 89 is your passport.deserializeUser function, so it still suggests that that is where your problem is.  Did the dummy data still trigger the error?